# Выражение "в разы"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сейчас модным стало выражение "в разы": ***В разы*** лучше рисует.

Мне это выражение очень режет слух.
Имеет ли оно право на существование — с точки зрения грамотной речи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал избегать этого выражения, особенно в случаях, подобных вашему примеру.

Вопрос постоянно поднимается на разных окололингвистических форумах, убедительных доводов в пользу использования выражения (как общелитературного) не приводилось.
Более того, далеко не всегда ясно, что оно вообще значит. Если это "короткий" синоним для "в несколько раз", то употребление его даже как просторечного должно быть строго ограничено областью величин, допускающих числовое измеренение. И только в этом случае я готов смириться  с его применением. Это уже не с русским языком связано, а с элементарным уважением к слушающему/читающему и к собственной речи.

В остальных же случаях надо гнать поганой метлой. Во фразах типа "шелковистость волос повышается в разы" смысла не больше, чем в рассуждениях о количестве ангелов на кончике иглы. Ибо нет в природе линейки, которой эту самую шелковистость можно измерить, выразить цифрой — и, соответственно, узнать количество этих разов.

Answer (score 0):

"Узнать количество этих разов" нельзя и по выражению "несколько раз", хотя негласным договором для таких случаев определена вилка (моё ощущение) **от четырёх до девяти**.

По сути, в перенесении во взрослую речь определённой детскости не будет беды, лишь бы оно дружило с грамотностью. "Разы" неправомерно возникли от: **Часы**, **Тазы**, **Носы**; неправомерно потому, что **Раз** не имеет своей множественной формы. "В разы" намекает на некое число раз, где каждый раз это - всегда (из раза в раз) - раз. Но! Но ведь у всякого есть свой номер и вес, - имя. Они - РАЗные числа и, стало быть, всегда разные "разы". Есть же ощутимая РАЗница - первый раз замужем или второй? Так что нет такого закона говорить **Раз** во множестве.

Answer (score 0):

В разы =  многократно. Абсолютно такая же "точность".
Считаю вполне допустимым в разговорной речи, а через неё - и в литературной(не в высоком, конечно, стиле). Бороться же надо с изменением традиционной орфографии в пользу безграмотных и ударений - в пользу диалектов, пусть даже и активно наступающих на норму.
Что же касается бытовизмов или даже вульгаризмов, то они имеют право на жизнь, отражая естественное развитие речи и не влияя на грамотность.

Comment: *С изменением орфографии - в пользу безграмотных*  - это очень грамотно, не находите? Можно изменять традиционную орфографию *в пользу* нетрадиционной, но какая польза от того будет безграмотным? Беда, коли борьбу за грамотность возглавляют такие же убежденные грамотеи, как и те, с кем им предстоит бороться... Что до сути, то да, "в разы" есть просторечно-разговорный синоним многократности, я об этом писал, но никак не общенормативный - на данном этапе, и вряд ли когда им станет. Тут Вы впереди паровоза бежите со своей безапелляционностью суждений.

Answer (score 0):

**РАЗ**, -а, *мн*. разЫ, раз, *м*.
 **2.** В сочетании с прилагательными, числительными или указательными местоимениями *указывает **место** данного действия, случая* и т.п. ***в ряду*** **других** повторяющихся действий случаев и т.п.:

*Постой, постой! Дай мне поглядеть на тебя **в последний раз**.* [ А.Островский, "Гроза" ]
*Вы будете благоразумны и не станете лгать, как **те разы**.* [Чехов, "Шведская спичка" ]

Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том III, **1959**.

Другого использования *"разы"* словарь того времени не предполагал.

Это выражение совсем новое, с пылу с жару, из сегодняшней устной речи.
 *«Доходы московских строительных компаний возросли **в разы**» — доносится из радиоприемника.* Что это значит? Вдвое, втрое? Наверное, даже больше: ***«в разы»*** **— это «в несколько раз».** Но до определенного рубежа, еще не вдесятеро — тогда бы говорили: «на порядок больше».
 Не стоит, наверное, культурным людям перенимать такое жлобское выражение: когда его произносят от своего имени интеллигентные радиожурналисты, это звучит явным диссонансом. Рискну высказать прогноз: не удержится это «в разы» в «великом и могучем», уйдет вместе со сточными водами языка.
[**словечко - мутант**](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1020690/15/Novikov_-_Novyy_slovar_modnyh_slov.html)

[**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%92%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B) ***называет "в разы" просторечным выражением, просторечным сочетанием, выходящим за рамки литературного языка.***

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, многие люди начинают употреблять те или иные выражения, услышав их от других и не думая, правильно это или не правильно. Просто кто-то один ляпнул, а другие по непонятной причине начинают повторять. Есть грамотное выражение "больше в несколько раз".
Если количество больше в 10 раз, можно сказать "больше на порядок". Это выражение тоже многие употребляют невпопад, не задумываясь и не понимая истинного значения.

Также некоторое время назад стало очень "модно" говорить "с большой долей вероятности", хотя понятия "доля вероятности" не существует. Есть вероятность того или иного события. Самое ужасное слышать, как такие *перлы* повторяют люди с математическим образованием.